# cXML and woocommerce for a punchout system

Tags: woocommerce, cxml-commercexml

I'm looking to integrate a cXML with woocommerce for a punchout system, and I have no idea where to start.
I was given the documentation found here: http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLGettingStarted.pdf

Any pointers on where and how to set this up?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can get an existing service for it ranging from https://www.punchout2go.com/, which is around a 1000 dollars a month to https://instapunchout.com/ which is between 30 and 50 dollars a month depending on your needs.

If you have time you can also develop it yourself, but there isn't much to find online aside from the PDF you already linked.

Comment: Anyone who already use instapunchout?

Comment: @Arelancelot Yeah, many, you can contact instapunchout.com to ask for references, or to just go ahead and start a free trial!

Comment: that might be best way. thanks